# Error on using pjsua2 in Netbeans

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, pjsip, pjsua2

I compiled pjsip, and now I'm trying to use pjsua2 in netbeans for an linux application. Using Swig I was able to get the java code, witch I copied as a package of my project. The project is in github on this link:

https://github.com/eduardobonfa/PjsipLinux

But when I try to run I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init()V
at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.<clinit>(pjsua2JNI.java:2619)
at org.pjsip.pjsua2.Endpoint.<init>(Endpoint.java:68)
at javaapplication3.test.main(MyAccount.java:44)
/home/eduardo/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What Do I need to do?

I compiled the pjsip using the following steps:

./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/lib

make dep && make && make install

go to swig folder

make

Got the java code and put in my project

Am I missing something??

Comment: you want to add libpjsua2.so in project_root_folder=>jniLibs=>armeabi folder.

Comment: this would work in Android project, I'm building for linux

Comment: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf follow this one for building for linux platform